# .rdlc report: text on page in two columns

Tags: rdlc

How do I split the text on the page in two columns in **.rdlc report**. For example Such as in the picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mo1x.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `Columns` and `ColumnSpacing` properties of your `rdlc`.

To do this you have to:

- display `Property` windows
- click on `Body` or `Report` (grey area outside your page), depending on what version you are using