# how to create rdlc report in two column format?

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I am very new to rdlc reports so this question might seem very silly.

I can paginate my rdlc reports using group by clause in the report designer. what I cannot do is divide the page into two columns. records 1 to 5 will show on the left and records 6 to 10 will show on the right. the same Pattern will be followed for subsequent pages.

[image]

can this even be done? please help!

Comment: Cant you use tabular format here?

Comment: @TheDictator I was not very clear in explaining my requirement. I have added a sketch to my question to make it more clear. By the way I AM USING TABULAR FORMAT

Comment: So basically you want two separate pages in one Report? Or just two colums? If two columns then take two rectangle and insert likewise

Comment: I need two columns of data in EACH PAGE. I do not understand how you can do it by taking two rectangles.

Comment: You just create two separate rectangles and in one rectangle bind this 1st grid view(if it is the) and in second the big one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.rdlc report: text on page in two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791307/rdlc-report-text-on-page-in-two-columns)