# How to create RDLC report in two column format inside Group?

Tags: .net, rdlc

As per title, I want to create the RDLC with two column inside Group.

I found that [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807003/how-to-create-rdlc-report-in-two-column-format) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791307/rdlc-report-text-on-page-in-two-columns) but that do not meet my requirements.

Below is the sample for what I want to display.
[image: Below is the sample for what I want to display.]

Thanks for your helps.